# Need to update variable in tkinter dynamically

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, updating

I'm trying to build a Sudoku Solver. Basic functionality is complete. I'm struggling with the GUI. I need the values inside the labels to be update in real-time so the users can see as to how the process is carried out. But what happens in my code is output is displayed after all the processing being done. Please help me out. Thanks a lot!

GitHub Repository :  https://github.com/KavijaKarunarathna/SudokuSolver
The whole project is pushed to this repository.
Please help me out. Means a lot to me

Comment: all GUIs don't like long running code like `time.sleep()` or `for`-loop. They simply wait to the end of `for`-loop to update data in widgets. This way they have to redraw window only once instead of redrawing hundred times (which can make flicking window). In `tkinter` you can use `root.update()` after every change in label to force `tkinter` to redraw window.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Can I know one more thing. Is there someway by which I can slow down the process so the users can really see whats going on

Comment: if you use `root.update()` then you can use also `time.sleep()` to slow down code - and  `root.update()` will force `tkinter` to redraw window, get keyboard/mouse events from system and send to widgets - so it will not freeze.